# fs writes file with web image link instead of the image itself

Tags: node.js, fs

I am using node's module fs.

When I run the following code:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {


        if (!fs.existsSync(`./${imageDescription}`)) {
            axios.get(imageUrl).then((images) => {
                fs.writeFile(`./${imageDescription}`, images.data['hits'][0]['largeImageURL'], function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    }
                    resolve(data);
                });
            });
        } else {
            fs.readFile(`./${imageDescription}`, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return;
                }
                resolve(data);
            });
        }
    });
```

Only the image url which starts with https:// and ends on .png is saved in a file, but I want the image itself to be saved there.

Comment: you would have to make another request before calling `fs.writeFile` to obtain the image since `images.data['hits'][0]['largeImageURL']` is only the URL

Comment: What does `images.data['hits'][0]` contain ? is that an image object ? in order to get the image itself, you either need to fetch the image as a file or get the base64 string of it then you do ```fs.writeFile(`./${imageDescription}.${imageExtension}`, imageBase64String, 'base64')```

Comment: @felmezit images.data['hits'][0] contains the image url

Comment: @XaviFont I see, then you want to fetch the image from the url and save it as a file in your desired path. In this case try to fetch the image as Blob so you can control its data using Response.blob(). After getting the image blob you can find diffrent ways to save that as a file. Check Response.[blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/blob).

Comment: Folks could more accurately help you if you include the actual URL you are making the axios call to.  Then, we could see exactly what it returns and how to best use that returned data to get to the image data itself.  As it is now, we're dealing with an entirely undocumented and undescribed piece of data and don't know what's in it.  Can't zero in on an exact, tested solution without being able to reproduce the situation with the proper URL.

Comment: You have quite a wild mixing of promises, callbacks and blocking synchronous code. You should get that straight too. Node's `fs` module also contains also a [promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_promises_api) for quite a while now. And synchronous checking of file existence in an async environment is pointless. Just try to access the file, and if it fails with an `ENOENT` do whatever you want to do on a nonexistent file

Comment: Also, you should avoid the promise anti-pattern where you're wrapping one promise inside of another and mixing promise code with plain callback code.  Nodejs has `fs.promise.readFile()` and `fs.promises.writeFile()` so you can use promises for the entire flow of control without wrapping anything in a manually created promise.  Then, you could also implement proper error handling using those promises.

Comment: `fs.writeFile(\`./${imageDescription}\`, images.data['hits'][0]['largeImageURL'], ...)` sure looks like you're telling it to write an URL rather than first fetching the data for that image URL and writing the actual image data.  And, that is apparently what your question states is happening too (you're just writing an URL).

Comment: And for what it is worth: you are never rejecting your outer promise on any error. So once an error happens, you are stuck with an ever-pending promise and everyone who waits on it will become old and gray ...

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find a piece of code that fetchs an image from a url and saves that with a random name and its extension.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { randomUUID } = require('crypto');
const axios = require('axios');

const imgUrl = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILTQq.png';
const randomId = randomUUID();
const fileExtension = imgUrl.split('.').pop();

axios
  .get(imgUrl, { responseType: 'stream' })
  .then((response) => {
    response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${randomId}.${fileExtension}`));
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```